# DataStreamException when trying to upload a file to OData service

Tags: android, odata, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I would like to find out the root cause of the exception thrown, in other words, which stream and why is closed.

I'm developing an Android app and I'm using the CV_ATTACHMENT_SRV OData service. The problem is that I cannot upload media to this service.

I created a ByteStream by using the method,

```
ByteStream content = ByteStream.fromInput(inputStream);
```

I tried to use the

```
createMedia(EntityValue entity, StreamBase content, HttpHeaders headers)
```

method of the service to upload an image where the entity is basically an instance of 'OriginalContent', the content is the ByteStream created earlier, and the headers contain some additional information related OriginalContent.

This is what I get:

```
com.sap.cloud.mobile.odata.DataStreamException: stream is closed  
at com.sap.cloud.mobile.odata.http.OKByteStreamBody.writeTo(OKByteStreamBody.java:46)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:59)  
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)  
...
```

I tried to figure out if I have access to the file I want to upload so I tried the above mentioned method with having a file on the external storage and packed in the apk. None of them worked.

Did you guys meet this kind of situation? I'm having a hard time finding similar situations. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested the solution lies within upgrading the dependencies from

```
implementation group: 'com.sap.cloud.android', name: 'fiori', version: 3.0.0
implementation group: 'com.sap.cloud.android', name: 'onboarding', version: 3.0.0
implementation group: 'com.sap.cloud.android', name: 'odata', version: 3.0.0
implementation group: 'com.sap.cloud.android', name: 'foundation', version: 3.0.0
```

to `3.0.5` (most likely if you update the `odata` lib, it will be fine).